# Installing visual python in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, python3

I am trying to install visual python in Ubuntu 18.04 from terminal using

```
sudo apt-get install python-visual 
sudo apt-get install libgtkglextmm-x1
```

Unfortunately it shows some message and installation fails.
How can I fix it and what are  other ways to install it?

Comment: In future, please add the exact error message you get, otherwise it may be impossible to diagnose the issue.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Anaconda 3.0 and see if that is something you'd consider.

Answer (score 6):

There is no `python-visual` package in the [18.04 LTS repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python-visual&searchon=names):

> [image: Python-Visual]

So consider to install using `pip3`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install vpython
python3 -c "from vpython import *; sphere()"
```

and you will get sphere in web-browser:

[image: vpython sphere]

Comment: Hello friend, In Ubuntu 18, I received ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vpython'  after successfully installing vpython using the method u mentioned. (But already have Anaconda 3.0 installed). Could it be that Anaconda is interfering with it? (I've heard that vpython is going obsolete)

Comment: You can try to remove Anaconda from the `$PATH` variable and retry.

Comment: I removed Anaconda and fixed the $PATH. This is what I received: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vpython/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .no_notebook import *
  File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vpython/no_notebook.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .vpython import *
  File "/home/name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/vpython/vpython.py", line 19, in <module>
    from numpy import arange
ImportError: cannot import name 'arange'